# Retrieve tree's states after load

Tags: extjs, tree

I updating my tree and to synchronize this with my JSON i using methods :

mystore.sync();
mystore.load();

If i don't using the second method, the tree don't show modifications ! With load method, tree collapse and the updates are effectives. But tree collapse even though before it was expand . How to restore state before load ??

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Yes, i 'm so sorry. I forgotten to accept responses !
i think now it's better . I validate all good answers :)

Thanks to your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can send list of expanded items to server, and generate your json with 'expanded: ture' according to expanded list.

Comment: If i understand, i adding "expanded : true" to the element wich updates in my JSON ?

Comment: no. You add 'expanded':'true' to elements from list of expended items

Comment: How to specified which items who are expanded ? 
In the docs , There are this method : 

TreeStore.ExpandPath(Path) , What is Path Parameter ?

Comment: something like:  var all = [];
tree.getView().node.cascadeBy(function(rec){
if (rec.get("expanded")) {
   all.push(rec);        
}      
   });